# Is it possible to pack a print result into excel or html?

Tags: python, html, excel

Hi I would like to show my print result on document file which supports font color(ex. Excel or HTML).

In order to show the result with font color, I have tried to pack it into exe and it worked!
But actually I want the result to show on document file.

I tried really hard to find how to pack result into excel or html on the Internet.
However, I can't find anything helpful.

I know there are some Excel modules to help me write the text into Excel.
I am afraid it is inconvenient to change font color for single text on Excel, because Excel is supposed to change color of "cells".

Could anyone give me a suggestion or a clue? 
I just want my result show on document with **colors**.

My code:

```
from colorama import Fore,Style,init
init()

text = 'now it is a test'
print(Fore.RED + text + Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openpyxl` to create a workbook and add your data to this workbook.

[How to use openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

[Style with openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've browsed the tutorial. It seems that I need to change my code as a openpyxl  way in order to write into Excel? Or you mean I could just copy part of my code into the 'openpyxl'?

Comment: You need to install openpyxl on your system and import it. You may want to read about installation of modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html). A tutorial about openpyxl is available [here](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/)

Comment: Yes, I know openpyxl installation is necessary. But I mean that, By using openpyxel, can I just print the result in Excel without changing my current code? That's why I asked how to pack my print result.

Comment: No you can't do it with just print the result in excel. You need to set the cell values by yourself.